# Ktor annotated interfaces as in Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

I was wondering if there is a way to annotate Ktor requests in a similar manner as in Retrofit (see example below), ie. as annotations on interface methods? Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything in the documentation regarding that.

Basically, this is what I would like to achieve:

```
@GET("event/{id}/entries?")
suspend fun getInitialEntries(
    @Path("id") id: Int,
    @Query("count") count: Int,
    @Query("debug") debug: Boolean) : LiveTicker
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Ktorfit](https://foso.github.io/Ktorfit/) - it's a client with Retrofit-style API, backed by Ktor.